# Hour and minute count as decimal

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I am working in LibreOffice Calc. I have a paycheck which for each day tells me the number of hours I worked, in this format `4:25`, ie 4 hours and 25 minutes.

**1.**

First of all, I want to type `4:25` into a cell, without Calc changing it to `04:25:00 AM`.

**2.**

Second, I want to calculate the total income, e.g. 4:25 at 11$ = 48.5833

**3.**

I need to sum up the column of durations, in `4:25` format, and display it in the same format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Use `[U]:MM` as format for your hour-cells.
2. Create a new cell with formula `=A1*24*11` where `A1` is the cell with the hours. `*24` is to convert the cell to hours and `*11` is your hourly rate. You can of course also do `=A1*24*$E$1` where `E1` would contains your hourly rate. Copy the cell down next to all the other hour-cells.
3. You can just `sum(A1:A99)` the hour cells (where `A1:A99` is the range of all your hours).
   If you make the resulting cell also format `[U]:MM` it will display your total hours.